# Highstock - Remove bottom date tooltip from line chart

Tags: highcharts

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to remove the bottom tooltip from a highstock line chart.  Can't find anything on this in the documentation.  In the attached image, I'm trying to remove the part that starts "Thursday, February 22..."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with just 1 CSS rule. Here you go:

```
    .highcharts-tooltip .highcharts-label:nth-child(1) {
        display: none;
    }
```